# Capture internal request calls in fiddler

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx, fiddler

I have web application and calling WCF and ASMX services internally to get the information.
But, In fildder I'm able to see the only web apllication aspx requests alone, not WCF and asmx service calls.

How I can captures those WCF and asmx calls in the Fiddler trafiice.

If fiddler has not having that option, please suggest some other tools.

Answer (score 10):

By default, Fiddler runs as a proxy server, which captures traffic that is passed through it.

When you run **Fiddler on your client**, your browser passes request through Fiddler on their way out to the server. If your client and server are on the same PC, traffic sent to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` might bypass Fiddler due to hardcoded limits in the .NET Framework (browsers don't have this problem).

To address this, you can update the .NET code to hit one of the *aliases* for `localhost` that Fiddler supports, to wit: `localhost.fiddler` or `ipv4.fiddler` or `ipv6.fiddler`.

If Fiddler is running **on the server** and you want to capture requests made by your serverside code (e.g. outbound requests from ASP.NET) then you need to configure your ASP.NET application to send its traffic to Fiddler. That's because, when Fiddler runs, it configures the *current user* to send its traffic to Fiddler, but ASP.NET runs inside a *Windows Service account* and not inside the current user's account. There are several ways to capture requests made from inside ASP.NET, but [this blog post](http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/01/08/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler) summarizes the simplest. Update the appropriate `machine.config` (usually the 64bit version of the file) to contain the line

`<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />`

Now, if Fiddler is running **on a different server** then you'd have to configure the proxy setting to point to whatever machine Fiddler *is* running on, e.g.

`<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://MyFiddlerServer:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />`

Comment: Hi Eric, my secnario is, we have web applications in QA/UAT/PROD servers. Internally these web applications are used some WCF services and asmx services. Now, I am browsing these QA/UAT/PROD web applications in my local PC and filddler is installed in my local PC only. In that case, How I can capture the internal WCF and asmx requests. Here there is no concpet of my local servers and nothing will be there in my local except browser and fiddler.

Comment: @user2783742 you need to edit the config file on the server hosting the QA/prod code, and make it point to your local machine. as indicated by EricLaw

Answer (score -2):

Fiddler works by intercepting web requests at one port (say 8888) then forwarding the request to the actual target port you've set up in WCF (say 8000). That's what allows Fiddler to capture the two-way traffic between the host and client.

So you need to have fiddler running on either the client or the host. Then, after starting Fiddler, go to the Tools menu and choose Fiddler Options, making sure it's listening on port 8888. Next, go to the Rules menu, select Customize Rules and add into the Handlers class some code like this:

```
if (oSession.host=="localhost:8888") { 
     oSession.host="localhost:8000";
}
```

Next, change your client application so that it's using 8888 (instead of the normal port #), then run the program. If setup properly, Fiddler will then act as a man-in-the-middle, intercepting and logging the requests and responses.

Good luck. If this works as an answer, don't forget to mark it.

Comment: Hi Brain,if it is in my local they way you suggested is correct. But, please the application hosted in QA/UAT/PROD environments then how to get the internal traffic. Both are applications and WCF services are in differnet servers.

Comment: OK, just substitute the URL of the QA or Prod server for "localhost" in the rules. So "MyQAServer:8888" instead of "localhost:8888".

Comment: Hi Brain, I tried with above suggestions. But no luck. can u pls suggest where exactly i need to change and my secnario is, we have web applications in QA/UAT/PROD servers. Internally these web applications are used some WCF services and asmx services. Now, I am browsing these QA/UAT/PROD web applications in my local PC and filddler is installed in my local PC only. In that case, How I can capture the internal WCF and asmx requests. Here there is no concpet of my local servers and nothing will be there in my local except browser and fiddler